# How to pipe a specific file to a find command?

Tags: bash, shell, unix

I am trying to redirect a specific file to the "find" command in bash shell by using the below command.

```
ls sample.txt | find -name "*ple*"
```

I would like to search the sub string `ple` in the filename `sample.txt` which I have passed, but the above command is checking for the match from all the files in the directory. It is not searching for the match in the specific file which I have passed using pipe.

Comment: please edit your Q to show what is your required output from your operation. If you're looking to do `ls -l` for your file, just do `find -name '*ple' -ls` (`find` is not designed to read from it's `stdin`). Good luck.

Comment: [`ls` is not an appropriate tool for programmatic use](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs). What's your actual goal, as opposed to the tools you think you want to use together?

Comment: Why do you think you need to use `find`? This should just be `grep ple sample.txt`

Comment: SO is for programming questions. unix.SE and SuperUser are the places to ask for help with using Unix command line tools.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the `grep` command not `find`, which crawls the file system.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for the sub string "ple" in the filename "sample.txt", then this code would do what you need:

```
mkdir -p /tmp/holder-file/ && cp /directory/sample.txt /tmp/holder-file/ && ls /tmp/holder-file/ | grep -e "ple"
```

Not super elegant but works great.

**Edit**: Thanks to Benjamin W. who came with a more elegant solution:

```
grep -e 'ple' <<< '/directory/sample.txt'
```

Comment: This would check the _contents_ of `sample.txt` for the string `ple`, not the filename. You'd have to, for example, use a here-string to do what you want: `grep 'ple' <<< '/directory/sample.txt'`

Comment: You're right. I misunderstood the question and will correct my answer.

Comment: Ok, corrected my answer, thanks for catching my mistake. By the way, your solution is very elegant.